# map.moveCamera in onLocationChanged()

Tags: java, android

I have this kind of problem: i'm using GoogleMaps map in my application in a Fragment and it breaks when the onLocationChanged method is called.
The problm is this line

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdatesFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15);

Probably because it can't find the mMap or i dunno.
Here it is the code part:

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

GoogleMap mMap;
Marker marker;

private void checkAndStartLocationUpdate() {
    if (permissionGranted && googleApiClientReady) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Start updating location");
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        try {

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

            lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.d("MainActivity", "Location update received: " + location.toString());

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    Log.d("MainActivity", longitude + " " + latitude);

    LatLng position = new LatLng(longitude, latitude);
    marker.setPosition(position);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by break? Can you post the crash report?

Comment: `requestLocationUpdates` call after `onMapReady`

Comment: Just add this check `if (mMap == null) {return;}` before `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));`

Comment: @code4rox the mMap is officially null, cause it doesn't move the camera. It returns from onLocationChanged.

Comment: @GautamSurani, nope! It's still not working changing the position of requestLocationUpdates.

Comment: The application crash, @MuhammadUmar!
12063-12063/com.example.punta.geopost E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main [...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Tika
    // Tika
    // Tika
}
```

and change

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));
```

to

```
if(mMap != null)
   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));
```

Or You can simply call

```
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

Inside of `onMapReady` after `mMap = googleMap;`

Comment: 'Mazing! Thank you so much!